# MS Access - Extract module & form code dependencies

Tags: ms-access, dependencies

I was wondering if there is there a way to export a diagram or something that shows the overview of a tool built in MS Access ?

Answer (score 1):

Check [MS Access Dependency Checker](http://www.accessdependencychecker.com/). Very useful free tool. Now it supports 64 bit Access

Comment: I will have a look and get back to you! Thank you !